# Where is the problem on showing letters with 'for' structure using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner of python and
I'm try to make a Hangman game using pygame.
I make some rectangles to show some buttons to click for inputs.
Now I try to show alphabets in each rectangles.
I try 2D-list, But I cannot find where it is wrong.

Here is my code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT, Rect
import sys

pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    sysfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 46)
    message = [[0]*4 for i in range(7)]
    message_rect = [[0]*4 for i in range(7)]

    for i in range(0, 7):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            if not ((i == 5 and j == 3) or (i == 6 and j == 3)):
                message[i][j] = sysfont.render(type(chr(65+7*j+i)), True, (0, 255, 0))
                message_rect[i][j] = message[i][j].get_rect()
                message_rect[i][j].center = (80 + 140 * i, 180 + 140 * j)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        SURFACE.fill((255, 255, 255))
        for i in range(0, 7):
            for j in range(0, 4):
                if not ((i == 5 and j == 3) or (i == 6 and j == 3)):
                    SURFACE.blit(message[i][j], message_rect[i][j])

        for i in range(0, 7):
            for j in range(0, 4):
                if not ((i == 5 and j == 3) or (i == 6 and j == 3)):
                    pygame.draw.rect(SURFACE, (0, 0, 0), (50+100*i, 150+100*j, 60, 60), 5)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this, I can see rectangles but not letters.
Where should I fix it and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st argument to `sysfont.render` has to be a string. [`chr(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) returns the string representation of an unicode code. Thus [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), which returns the type of an object, is superfluous:

<s>`message[i][j] = sysfont.render(type(chr(65+7*j+i)), True, (0, 255, 0))`</s>

```py
message[i][j] = sysfont.render(chr(65+7*j+i), True, (0, 255, 0))
```

Further more the computation of the position of the letters is generates an increasing misaligned result, for increasing indices, because the offset between the letters is to larg:

<s>`message_rect[i][j].center = (80 + 140 * i, 180 + 140 * j)`</s>

```py
message_rect[i][j].center = (80 + 100 * i, 180 + 100 * j)
```

Change the code as follows, to solve the issue:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    for i in range(0, 7):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            if not ((i == 5 and j == 3) or (i == 6 and j == 3)):
                message[i][j] = sysfont.render(chr(65+7*j+i), True, (0, 255, 0))
                message_rect[i][j] = message[i][j].get_rect()
                message_rect[i][j].center = (80 + 100 * i, 180 + 100 * j)

    # [...]
```